# Trouble with installing wxWidgets-3.0.2 for Code::Blocks

Tags: wxwidgets

I follow the instructions of [wxWiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started) to install it. When I type `make`, I see sliding texts. At the end, I type `make` again to see everything is ok. But it gives me this:

```
void@linux:~/wxWidgets-3.0.2/gtk-build> make

(if test -f utils/wxrc/Makefile ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/emre/wxWidgets-3.0.2/gtk-build/utils/wxrc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/emre/wxWidgets-3.0.2/gtk-build/utils/wxrc'
```

Comment: what is the trouble? Everything was build sucessfully...

Comment: Thank you. But how did you understand? Isn't it supposed to give something like '.......is up to date'. It is from my earlier 'make' experiences.

Comment: Maybe you should post it as answer.